# SleekXMPP is not handling headline type messages ( openfire )

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am trying to handle all messages which are received by the SleekXMPP client ( from openfire ) using the following handler

```
 self.add_event_handler("message", self.onmessage)
```

And the method

```
def onmessage(self,msg):
```

print('I am in onmessages..!!')
        if msg['type'] in ('error','headline','groupchat'):
            print "%s" % msg

I am able to print messages of type "groupchat" , However I am not getting any messages printed out when I receive messaage of type "headline".

I have verified that my connection is receiving these messages by enabling DBUG mode.

Any ideas why my message handler is not processing headline messages ?

```
EX. groupchat message i got (which is successfully processed by the handler)


<message to="13260827@chat/resource" type="groupchat" id="m_444"
 from="beach@resource/Chatadmin1 HOST"><body>user06</body>
 <html xmlns=""><body xmlns="">user06</body></html></message>"

EX. headline message I want to process with the same handler (which is not working ATM)

<message to="13260827@chat/resource" type="headline" from="chat">
<x xmlns="domain:mute">
<mute duration="5" reasonCode="mute.reason.swearing" expiryTime="1416483206670" />
</x></message>
```

Many thanks in advance for an explaination/solution ;)

Comment: Isn't SleekXMPP open source? If so, can't you just look at the source and debug it to see what's happening with headline type messages?

Comment: @Flow : I completely agree with you, But unfortunately I have recently started learning python it self. Still I have tried to look into the code but couldn't understand it fully thus posting on stack overflow. Anyway thanks a lot for the advice.

Comment: Alright, I really recommend exploiting the power of open source. Solving such questions is also the best way to learn.

Comment: @Flow : Finally I have figured out how to do this. Thanks for the excellent documentation of sleekxmpp and the examples they provided. Special thanks to you ( Flow ) for forcing me to look in to the source :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the above question is explained here (Similar example):
https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/tree/develop/examples/custom_stanzas

Basically I need to register a custom stanza since we are including name spaces in stanza's which are very specific to our domain.

```
<message type="headline" from="chat" to="13269603@chat/resource">
    <comp xmlns="xxxx:comp" type="currency">
        <currency xmlns="xxxx:currency">
            <amount>1.00</amount>
            <iso-code>GBP</iso-code>
        </currency>
    </comp>
</message>
```

Step 1: Create a class like following

```
class Currency(ElementBase):
    namespace = 'xxxx:currency'
    name = 'currency'
    plugin_attrib = 'currency'
    interfaces = set(('amount', 'iso-code'))
    sub_interfaces = interfaces


class Comp(ElementBase):
    namespace = 'xxxx:comp'
    name = 'comp'
    plugin_attrib = 'comp'
    interfaces = set(('type', 'currency'))
    sub_interfaces = interfaces
    subitem = (Currency,)

def getCurrency(self):
    currency = {}
    for cur in self.xml.findall('{%s}currency' % Currency.namespace):
        cur = Currency(cur)
        currency[cur['amount']] = cur['iso-code']
    return currency
```

You can have more util methods based on your requirements

Step 2:

register the stanza like below (This should be done in client class (see examples for this ))

```
register_stanza_plugin(Message, Comp)
```

Step 3: Register the event

```
self.registerHandler(
        Callback('Comp Message', StanzaPath('{%s}message/{%s}comp' % (self.default_ns,self.default_ns)),self.oncomp))

def oncomp(self, msg):
    self.event('custom_action', msg)
```

Step 4: Handle the event

```
self.add_event_handler('custom_action',
                           self.handle_action_event)

def handle_action_event(self, msg):
    print("I am in handle_action_event***************")
    print(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason maybe; you should do some changing core of openfire source code.

1. You entered openfire->src->java
2. entered package org.jivesoftware.openfire;
3. entered OfflineMessageStore.java
4. 480 510 rows found, case headline return false,  you should changing
   true.

Comment: From Review: I could not completely understand your answer. Did you mean these are instructions to fix the issue, or did you mean that eventually the author of the question changed openfire's core by mistake? Also the URLs you provided are all broken. Please edit your answer and clarify / fix these issues.

Comment: Sorry, new url: https://i.hizliresim.com/b6v2pG.png     If the openfire person is offline, the headline message is not saved in the off-line table, and the message is not transmitted when the person logs in. In order for this message to be delivered, you need to take the steps mentioned above.

Comment: It says the image cannot be display because it contains errors. Do you know it is possible to upload images directly to stackoverflow's answer? Please see: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). These review comments can all be removed later. Please use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51684905/edit) to edit your answer.

Comment: i can't upload image because;It said  'You need at least 10 reputation to post images'